# Nodejs number of concurrent request affect performance

Tags: node.js, performance, concurrency, sequelize.js

I am facing a very serious performance issue in our project. In one of the specific Get request, I am doing multiple(sql queries to database). I prepared all promises and Promise.all them at the very end.

```
const getA$ = getAFromDB();
const getB$ = getBFromDB();
....

const [A, B, ...] = await Promise.all([getA$, getB$]);
```

I used Jmeter to performance testing my endpoint, the below behaviour is observed.

`1 request:  Average response time :  100ms`

`10 concurrent request:   Average response time : 200+ms`

`20 concurrent request:   Average response time : 300+ms`

`50 concurrent request:   Average response time : 500+ms`

The number of concurrent request increases, the higher average response time I got. I configured my sequelize.js connection pool

```
 "pool": { max: 55, min: 0, idle: 10000 }
```

What is wrong here ? Am I not using node correctly or this is the general behaviour ?

Comment: It isn't possible to say without knowing how expensive your DB operations are. They could be fetching a huge amount of data (network delay), or they could be doing something computationally intensive and the DB is unable to respond quickly. This may not be a node issue at all - maybe your DB just needs an index or two. I'd recommend starting by debugging your database performance.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a try